# Power-In + Video-Out + USB Out for mobile phone? (Samsung S8)

Tags: usb

I am looking for a cheaper alternative for the `Samsung Dex Station` or `Samsung Dex Pad`.

Some phones like my Samsung S8, which happens to be a [Samsung Dex compatible device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_DeX) can be turned into a full android desktop computer using a `Samsung Dex Station` or `Samsung Dex Pad`.

A `USB-C Hub/multiport adapter` is a device that connects to a computer or phone via USB-C, and allows me to connect a USB-B device (like a wireless mouse and keyboard combo) and a HDMI monitor.

When I use a regular `USB-C Hub/multiport adapter` with the Samsung S8, the phone connects to the monitor, keyboard and mouse, providing a similar experience to the expensive `Samsung Dex Station` or `Samsung Dex Pad`, with one big exception: The phone does not charge, the battery drains slowly. I've heard some usb-c hubs do charge the device they connect to, but I dont know which ones. So, the question...

What is the name of the 'feature' that the `USB-C Hub` must have so I can recognize if it will transfer power to the master device?

EDIT: For what it's worth, and answering my own question: What I needed was a `PD` / `Power Delivery` `USB-C Hub' with HDMI.

It's unbelievable that this question is off-topic on this site. This community is broken.

Comment: I can close this as "unclear what you're asking" instead, if you like. You're looking for... what, exactly? A hub that you can plug into a PC? With a USB-C charge lead for an S8, a USB-A mouse, and... what video outputs? USB-C HDMI isn't a thing - do you mean a USB-C port _and_ an HDMI port? If you can clarify what kind of device you're looking for and specify what outputs it needs to have, we may be able to reopen this question.

Comment: I am asking what *kind of device* do I need, because I don't know how to google exactly what my options are. Is that off-topic for this site?

Comment: I want to turn a mobile phone into a full android desktop computer with mouse and keyboard. I already did this with a regular USB-C hub, except it doesn't charge my phone battery so eventually it gets empty, and I want it 24x7 turned on and connected. So, I need a "regular USB-C hub" that also charges the phone at the same time, all via the same and only phone usb-c port. There is no PC involved.

Comment: [Meta discussion](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/649/364) about this question.

Comment: @AndrewT. still not good enough for reopen?

Comment: Looks perfectly clear to me.  Maybe if you list out the specs of the hub you have (what it does that you need), and then *add* to that list, "charges the phone/device it is plugged into."  In other words, list out all the specs you need, and just note that you have a device (model such-and-so) that fulfills all of the specs except for the last one.

Comment: @GerardoGrignoli, This question was very close to being acceptable on this site. The thing you didn't do that would have made it on-topic was **explicitly asking for a recommendation** for a product that had the feature you were asking for. Your question fell short of a "recommendation" type question because you just wanted the name of a feature, which is a question that is on-topic for *other* stack exchange sites. I'm glad that you eventually found the answer though.

Comment: You said it @Romen. Hardware Recs only allows to list specs and ask for users to answer which specific brand/models. My question was legitimate. Was about asking for a spec that lead to a purchase decision. Even though, it is off-topic because the scope defined for this site is ridiculously narrow.